# How to lock and immediately turn off screen in LUbuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, power-management, lock-screen

I'm running LUbuntu 18.04, with the lightdm greeter, as well as LXDE. I want to set up a keystroke that immediately powers off the screen (*not* just blanking!) as well as locks it so that when I wake up the screen I have to enter my password.  So far, it seems I can do either one but not both together.

One keystroke is set to run: `xset dpms force off`

The powers off the screen, but when I wake it up I am back where I was without a lock screen.

Another keystroke is set to run: `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`

This sends me to the lock screen, but the display does not power off until the idle time is reached, which is 5 minutes later.

I tried creating a script that would wait a couple seconds (so that releasing the key doesn't wake up the screen) then run the command to turn the screen off, then switcher to the greeter.  The screen turns off, but as soon as the greeter is activated, it automatically turns the screen back on, defeating the whole point.  I tried in the reverse order, but once the screen lock is activated the screen is not powered off.  There is no message from the command to indicate why.

The Xcfe power manager only provides the means to automatically switch the monitor off after a certain idle time.   Under the "Security" tab there is an option (checked" to Automatically lock the session "When the screensaver is activated" but there is apparently no screensaver (the Preferences menu has no screensaver option).  I was thinking that perhaps there is a command to make LXDE think the screensaver is started (while actually e.g. powering off the screen) but the man page for lxsession-default only says available commands are defined in `desktop.conf.examples` which is not present on my system. I did find `desktop.conf` and it lists "screensaver" as a command but no associated command, and running `lxsession-default screensaver` just  prints `screensaver` and otherwise does nothing.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 as well as any other flavor of the same vintage is out of support (flavors get only 3 years) therefore off-topic here. Please upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: @Nmath I did that, but as described above, it didn't work.  Perhaps there is another command I am not aware of that will do the trick?

Comment: do i understand well, you try to turn off the screen although the greeter is active? I am confused because while the greeter is active nobody should be able to see what you have done during your session. I dont have a solution for you but perhaps your script acts different when using a systemd service file that runs your commands in sequence, instead of using a simple script.

Comment: @Yes, I tried both ways, power off, then greeter, and greeter first, followed by power off.  The purpose of the greeter is to prevent anybody else from using the machine, the purpose of the screen off is to prevent the light from the backlight from lighting up the dark room.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `lxhotkey` program has an extra "save" step after editing the command and clicking the checkmark.  My script was not working because it was not being executed.  When the display is powered off the screen is automatically locked after any display set under the Xfce Power Manager > Security tab and running the greeter is not necessary.  It's also necessary to delay a short amount of time before turning the display off to prevent the keystroke release from turning the screen back on (unless you are really quick releasing the keystroke).